# find the domain of ${1-5^x/(7^{-x})-7}^{-1/2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried removing the values at which denominator is zero but it isnt right.

P.S. - Answer is $(-\infty,-1] \cup [0,\infty)$.

Comment: The square root should have positive argument.

Comment: As written, $x$ may be any real number.

Comment: @Amitrochates you surely ignored some parentheses. As written, the expression is defined for any real $x.$

Answer (score 0):

Your term can be written as $$1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}-35^x$$ and the domain is given by $$x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: I think you mean $1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}-35^x$

Answer (score 0):

Either the answer you have cited is incorrect or the expression you indicated in the title is incorrect.

Going by what you have in the title:

$$ 1 - 5^{x}/(7^{-x}) - 7^{-1/2} = 1 - \frac{5^{x}}{7^{-x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}} $$

$$ = 1 - \frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)^{x}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}} = 1 - 5^{x}7^{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}} $$

$$ = 1 - 35^{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}$$

Therefore, the domain of the expression is all real numbers.